# I cannot install a python package (opencv)

Tags: python, pip, package

When I install OpenCV package by pip in Ubuntu 18.04
it pauses and shows this message:
"
defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rebooting the PC is an effective way to solve this issue.